# onclick should not be executed when validationMessageFor helper got any messages in screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am using validationMessageFor helper in my view. I am using input type submit along with some onclick functionality that i require. I have an array in click function. what happening is eventhough validation messages are displayed in screen still that function in executed and array is updating with empty values. i dont want to update the array when fields are empty or validation messages are displayed.
There is a way for this to check every field in method and update the array. But is there any good way for this?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="step1Next">Next </button> 
$("#step1Next").click(function () { 
    var objPrdVM = { 
        PurchaseDate: $('.pickDate').val(), 
        InvoiceNumber: $('#InvoiceNumber').val(), 
        InvoiceFile: "123", 
        CategoryId: document.getElementById('CategoryName').selectedIndex,
        ProductId: document.getElementById('ProductId').selectedIndex, 
        Quantity: $('#Quantity').val() 
    } 

    arrPrdVM.push(objPrdVM); 
} //where arrPrdVM is globaly declared
```

Comment: Post relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="step1Next">Next </button> $("#step1Next").click(function () { var objPrdVM = {
            PurchaseDate: $('.pickDate').val(),
            InvoiceNumber: $('#InvoiceNumber').val(),
            InvoiceFile: "123",
            CategoryId: document.getElementById('CategoryName').selectedIndex,
            ProductId: document.getElementById('ProductId').selectedIndex,
            Quantity: $('#Quantity').val()
        }
        arrPrdVM.push(objPrdVM); } //where arrPrdVM is globaly declared @Ravi

Comment: i dont want to update the array unless all validation fields are filled. Is there any way without checking every field is empty or not @Ravi

Comment: It is difficult to understand the code you posted. Could you please format the code and post again. Place it in the question body.

Comment: how can i format the code, could you please help me. This is my first question in stack overflow @Ravi

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: ok but how to format the code from comment box? @ravi